# Soap Setter Getter android

Tags: android

I successfully extract tag from xml content using jsoup for one element.

```
  class Post {

    private String a;
    private String b;


    public void setA (String a){
           this.a = a;

    }


    public void setB(String b){
           this.b =b;

    }

    public String getA(){

    return a;
    }

    public String getB(){

    return b;
    }

   }
```

by using arraylist

```
public ArrayList<Post> PostList = new ArrayList<Post>();
```

So how can i store the values of a b under different index using jsoup. i extract single tag

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(soap_xml_content);

Element element1 = doc.select("a");
Element element2 = doc.select("b");
Element compte = doc.select("comptes");

String value_a = element1.text();
String value_b = element2.text();

Post currentPost = new Post();
```

for each `compte` I want to set the element a and b in Post class and acess it using method get.

```
for( Element element : compte ){

                System.out.println(": "+element);
                currentPost.setA(element);
                            currentPost.setB(element);
                            Poslist.add(currentPost);
                            currentPost = new Post();
            }
```

i know am wrong but i don't know how to do this step
please help.

---

**Xml:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soap:Body> 
        <liste> 
            <comptes> 
                <a>pen drive</a> 
                <b>jsoup</b> 
            </comptes> 
            <comptes> 
                <a>pen drive</a> 
                <b>jsoup</b> 
            </comptes> 
            <comptes> 
                <a>pen drive</a> 
                <b>jsoup</b> 
            </comptes> 
        </liste> 
    </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>



04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null format argument
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2173)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2151)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at .Convertor$loadingTask.doInBackground(Convertor.java:201)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at .Convertor$loadingTask.doInBackground(Convertor.java:1)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Constructor in Your Post class public Post(A,B)

```
public Post(String a, String b){
 this.a =a;
 this.b =b;

}
```

and:

```
for( Element element : compte ){

    System.out.println(": "+element);

    Poslist.add(new Post(ElementA,ElementB));

}
```

You wont be using Setters with the above solution. You are just adding Objects of class in your ArrayList of type Post. To use the get method you will do it like this.

```
String A = Poslist.get(YOUR_POSTION).getA();
String B = Poslist.get(YOUR_POSTION).getB();
```